# Why do we need to add parentheses to eval JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Why does the following code needs to add `(` and `)` for eval?

```
var strJson = eval("(" + $("#status").val().replace(";","") + ")");
```

PS: `$("#status").val()` is returning something like `{"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"};`

Comment: Why are you using `eval` in the first place? Just stick with:

    `var strJson = $("#status").val().replace(";","");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` takes a JavaScript statement or expression, but `{...}` would be valid as a statement *or* an expression, and the grammar of JavaScript prefers a statement.

As an expression:

```
{"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"}
```

is an Object with some properties (what you want).

As a statement, it is a block:

```
{                       // begin Block
    "10000048":         // LabelledStatement (but the quotes are invalid)
        "1",            // Expression, calculate string "1" then discard it, then
            "25000175": // you can't put a label inside an expression
```

which gives an error.

(JavaScript labels can be used to label a particular statement for use with `break`/`continue`. They're a bit pointless and almost never used.)

So by adding the parentheses you resolve the ambiguity. Only an expression can start with `(`, so the contents are parsed in an expression context, giving an object literal,  not a statement context.

Incidentally this is not *quite* enough to correctly interpret all possible JSON values. Due to an oversight in JSON's design, the characters U+2028 and U+2029, two obscure Unicode line-ending characters, are valid to put unescaped in a JSON string literal, but not in a JavaScript string literal. If you want to be safe, you can escape them, eg:

```
function parseJSON(s) {
    if ('JSON' in window) return JSON.parse(s);
    return eval('('+s.replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028').replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029')+')');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends what the value in that element is (an unknown), wrapping it in `()` is the safe route to account for possibly of *no* input being there.

Edit: Now that you've cleared up it's JSON, this isn't valid:

```
eval('{"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"}');
```

But this will result in a valid object being returned:

```
eval('({"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"})');
//effectively:
eval('return {"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"};');
```

Picture in a JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  {"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"}
</script>
```

This is going to fail, it's just an object declared inline but not proper syntax...the same reason a server *has* to support JSONP for it to work.

---

A bit tangential to the question, but since you're including jQuery, you might as well use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) (which will use the native `JSON.parse()` if available) for this:

```
var strJson = $.parseJSON($("#status").val().replace(";",""));
```

Comment: Hi the val() returned is something like {"10000048":"1","25000175":"2","25000268":"3"};

Comment: why the first statement is invalid

Comment: @Ricky - It's just not valid syntax for the same reason it's not directly in script, since the parser isn't looking at it as an expression whereas adding the `()` effectively is a return statement (since it switches to an expression, recognizing `{` as an object start, getting/returning the object you care about).