# Why eval is not working in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to know whats wrong with following JavaScript code -

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var p = eval('new { "Color":"Red"}');

alert(p.Color);
</script>
</html>
```

It is giving me JavaScript error as -

```
Message: Object doesn't support this action
Line: 4
Char: 1
Code: 0
```

Comment: Not answering your question but why not: var p = { "Color":"Red"}'?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why is `var p={"Color":"Red"}` not good enough?

Comment: @Kolink- that code will be embedded from server side coding and it is dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with the code;

firstly you're telling the script to create something new, but you're not telling it *what* to create. If you aren't creating a custom object, you are creating an Object object, so you need to tell it that:

```
var p = eval('new Object()');
```

Now that you are creating a new Object object, you can configure the Color property:

```
var p = eval('new Object({"Color":"Red"})');
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Dcr2/)

But, why are you using eval in the first place? [eval is evil](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)!

Answer (score 1):

> Why eval is not working in this snippet?

Because you cannot use the [`new` operator *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) with objects, only with functions.

`{"Color":"Red"}` is  evaluated as object literal and not as function.

If you want to parse JSON, use [`JSON.parse` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON). See also [JSON.parse vs. eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval).

Or create the object literal directly, if it is static:

```
var p = {"Color":"Red"};
```

---

To make it work with `eval` ([which you should avoid to use anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil)), remove `new` and wrap the literal in parenthesis:

```
var p = eval('({"Color":"Red"})');
```

[The parenthesis are necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820488/why-do-we-need-to-add-parentheses-to-eval-json) because otherwise JavaScript would evaluate `{"Color":"Red"}` as a *block* and throw an error.