# Surround an object declaration with parenthesis

Tags: javascript

Curious why the author surrounded object declaration with parenthesis [here](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground/blob/master/js/rtpg.map.js#L36)

```
rtpg.map.START_KEYS = ({"Key 1":"Value 1", "Key 2":"Value 2", "Key 3":"Value 3", "Key 4":"Value 4"});
```

why not:

```
rtpg.map.START_KEYS = {"Key 1":"Value 1", "Key 2":"Value 2", "Key 3":"Value 3", "Key 4":"Value 4"};
```

Comment: for no reason at all? maybe some leftover of what was previously there?

Comment: maybe this is one reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820488/why-do-we-need-to-add-parentheses-to-eval-json

Comment: @sza But where is `eval` in this code? And it's not a statement. So none of that SO question is relevant

Comment: @lan I think the parenthesis is used for forcing to convert json to an object though the json self is an object.

Comment: @sza: [replying to comment #1] Close, but not quite -- following `=`, that _must_ already be an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @sza: [replying to comment #2] No, there is no JSON here. JSON is a data interchange format that looks like JavaScript's object literal syntax. This here is simply an object literal. No JSON at all.

Comment: Just so we can put SO questions on it!

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer: I bet you're right; unfortunately that repo only has one revision, so we can't prove it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no functional difference.**

In the case that you emplace JSON text in an `eval` call to obtain a JavaScript object, [you have to use parentheses to disambiguate the resulting expression from a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3820660/560648), but that is not the case here: the object literal follows a `=` token and can therefore be parsed only as an expression, with no disambiguation required.

The author has therefore done it out of:

- consistency, or
- preference, or
- ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there is some value in specifying parenthesis when using `eval`, but that is not the case here. In this particular code snippet, either way would work exactly the same, so for whatever reason this was just the author's preference.